# Footer has weird whitespace under it

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

So I tried to make a sticky footer with Flexboxes/`<Grid container>`

[Code here(Codesandbox)](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonky-footer-q4150)

The problem is that the footer has a weird whitespace under it.

[image: Whitespace Picture]

I tried some stuff out and found, that the whitespace dissapears, if I put smaller text in the first grid item of the footer.

[image]

I can't seem to figure out where this whitespace comes from.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about this? https://nimb.ws/au6Ygp

Comment: @m4n0 yes that's what i mean, i have no idea where it comes from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example Workflow using Firefox

- press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `C` to open the inspector
- click on your footer
- go up in the hierarchy until you find the space
- in this case its body with a margin
- set margin: 0 on body
- done

Edit:

- the margin on the body would still be there even with the new fix
- now that we know its only in full screen mode visible we open the inspector there
- and we see the space is in footer where the div in it does not stretch to the bottom we just don't have that much content
- the flex container surounding it could fix it but for some reason wrap is turned on
- not sure if you want your footer to wrap to the top, but turning it off fixes the space since main content div has flex grow turned on

Comment: I tried your solution of setting the margin of the body to 0. This didn't help with the whitespace.

Comment: @Highom maybe this fix helps, could not know you did not mean the first one

Answer (score 0):

in you code of app.js add margin:0; it's work form me
using react.js ,or change the text editor and work on full page with the inspector to recognize your problem ,may be problem editor in compiling

```
body: {
        margin:"0",//This Added
        height: "100vh",
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default
      }
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to remove the margin in the demo, so it was misleading, this isn't the issue. The Issue is with the big whitespace seen in the first screenshot.